# in R, Can I get only the names columns of a csv(txt) file?

Tags: r

I have many big files. But I would like get only the names of the columns without load them. 
Using the data.table packages, I can do

```
df1 <-fread("file.txt")
names1<- names(df)
```

But, for get all names of the all files, is ver expensive.  There is some other option?

Comment: Read the documentation of `?fread` and pay special attention to the 4th argument.

Comment: oh! fread really works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many functions to read in data have optional arguments that allow you to specify how many lines you'd like to read in. For example, the [read.table](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/read.table) function would allow you to do:

```
df1 <- read.table("file.txt", nrows=1, header=TRUE)

colnames(df1)
```

I'd bet that `fread()` has this option too.

(Note that you may even be able to get away with nrows=0, but I haven't checked to see if that works)

### EDIT

As commenter kindly points out, `fread()` and `read.table()` work a little differently.

For `fread()`, you'll want to supply argument `nrows=0` :

```
df1 <- fread("file.txt", nrows=0) ##works
```

As per the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/data.table/docs/fread),

> `nrows=0` is a special case that just returns the column names and types; e.g., a dry run for a large file or to quickly check format consistency of a set of files before starting to read any.

But `nrows=0` is one of the ignored cases when supplied in `read.table()`

```
df1 <- fread("file.txt") ##reads entire file    
df1 <- fread("file.txt", nrows=-1) ##reads entire file
df1 <- fread("file.txt", nrows=0) ##reads entire file
```

Comment: What is this *I"d bet*? Can't you read the docs like you did for `read.table`?

Comment: Good point, @DavidArenburg, I should have supplied that. I was being lazy. Thank you.